# HSD.test gives MSD value instead of HSD value

Tags: r, anova, tukey, posthoc

I performed a post hoc test using HSD.test from agricolae package, but the result is MSD value instead of HSD. And in some cases, the ANOVA result fitted using aov would be significant (p<0.05), but HSD.test would not output HSD or MSD value. Any idea why, please?

```
    HSD.test(model, trt = "Groups")

> summary(aov)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)    
Groups       2  29696   14848   36.87 5.3e-11 ***
Residuals   57  22953     403                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**HSD.test output**

```
$statistics
  MSerror Df     Mean       CV      MSD
   402.69 57 82.90807 24.20408 15.27061
```

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Tukey HSD is used to make multiple pair-wise comparisons. The result of those pairwise comparisons can be found by, say:

```
anova<- aov(df, y~x)
hsd <- HSD.test(anova, trt ='x')
print(hsd$groups)
```

Where the result of the pair-wise comparisons have been converted to letters to represent statistically similar groups. I believe that `MSD` value under `$statistics` is only used in the calculations of groups.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Before now, `HSD.test` used to output the `HSD` value in addition to the letter if `group = TRUE` is maintained. But now the value is that of `MSD` instead of `HSD`. I don't know why that is happening